# How to return result from a delegate

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I change this class to return me stream which I can send back to browser ?

I am trying to create a Excel file using report viewer and send it back to client who is using a browser,

```
 public class WebReportRenderer : IDisposable
{
    private ReportViewer rvInstance;
    private IList<Stream> m_streams;

    public WebReportRenderer(string reportPath, string downloadFileName, string dataSetName, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        rvInstance = new ReportViewer();
        rvInstance.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
        rvInstance.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        rvInstance.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSetName, dataTable));
        rvInstance.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }

    public void RenderToBrowserExcel()
    {
        var callback = new CreateStreamCallback(CreateWebBrowserStream);
        Warning[] warnings;

        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        rvInstance.LocalReport.Render("EXCELOPENXML", null, callback, out warnings);

        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;
    }

    private Stream CreateWebBrowserStream(string name, string extension, System.Text.Encoding encoding, string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new FileStream(name + "." + extension, FileMode.Create);
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.rvInstance != null) this.rvInstance.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now If I call `WebReportRenderer(... all para).RenderToBrowserExcel()` it will create a stream and add it to `m_streams` but I am not sure if I should make it public then get the results from it ?

Not really sure what is the best way to design this class. I will also need to add following to it maybe in WCF method or somewhere in this report renderer class,

```
var outGoingResponse = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
 outGoingResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
 outGoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment";
```

**Disclaimer:**

I took some code from here - 
http://www.danielroot.info/2009/06/how-to-render-reporting-services.html